# How to quickly filter sensitive words without removing characters?

Tags: python, filtering

I have a question considering sensitive word filtration. While my basic code can detect the word and filter it out, say if our sensitive word was 'example', if I typed 'exam ple', the system would not identify this as a sensitive word. While this isn't really Python-specific, I would still like to ask if anyone has a way to filter out things like 'exam ple'. Also, I prefer not to use the *remove spaces and underscores* methods as they take too long.

*Note:*
I can manually implement a feature to except words which look like the sensitive word, but are not related to it. In other words, I'll deal with the error correction.

Comment: You don't have to actually remove them, just ignore them when filtering — which *might* be slightly faster. I can think of multiple ways of ignoring them…

Comment: @martineau I appreciate your comment, but I would like the system to be almost instant as it is being used in more critical areas. Though thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with it if you find them but you could use regex and just make the regex statement such that it includes spaces, underscores, etc as you see fit. i.e. include spaces between each letter in 'example' like `re.compile('e\s*x\s*a\s*m\s*p\s*l\s*e', re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @KelVarnsen I'm not very sure I understand what you mean, though that may just be my brain. For more context about my question, I have an excel document which contains the sensitive words. It will read through all the words, and for each word in the document, it will compare them to the content provided. For example, 'example' could be one of those words, but if the content was 'exam ple', it would consider it ok, but I don't want it to do that. Do you have any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you want to use regex matching. Not sure how familiar you are with it, but you if you wanted to match the phrase "ab", even if there are spaces in between, you can use a regex expression like 'a\s*b' which will try to match the letter a, followed by 0 or more spaces, and then the letter b. There are other settings (flags) you can add as well such as case insensitivity. You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: Using a regex is one way to ignore them, but not necessarily a fast way. The only way to know for sure would be to do some timing test vs other ways.

Comment: Can you show your working solution that takes too long, so that answers can be compared against it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to split the string of words into a list, and loop over the list of words (and possible word fragments) looking at each word, and also the sum of that word with the next. In doing so, a convenient `break` strategy comes about with the `try-except` idiom:

```py
bad_words = ["foo", "bar"]
the_list = the_string.split()

i = 0
while True:
  try:
    if the_list[i] in bad_words:
      del the_list[i]
    if the_list[i] + the_list[i+1] in bad_words:
      del the_list[i]
      del the_list[i+1]
  except IndexError:
    break
  else:
    i += 1

the_string = " ".join(the_list)
```